# How to print an integer zero-filled to a.given width?

Tags: bash, integer, width

I am doing something like this with bash

```
number=1
while [ $number -le 10 ]; do
    echo $number
    number=$((number+1))
done
```

This will output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

.

What can I do if I want the total digits of the integer as, e.g., two. If the integer has fewer digits than two, then fill with zero on the left. In other words, I want output like this:

```
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
```

Is there someone knowing how to manage this? Thanks:)

Comment: Not "bits", (decimal) digits.

Answer (score 3):

Use `printf` instead of `echo`:

```
printf "%02d\n" $number
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. And also thank for the revision of my English:)